# Is it possible to have a float number without a decimal point in Python?

Tags: python, numbers

I asked this because it is possible in R. Note that both 1.5 and 1 are in numeric type (double-precision), and only 1L is an integer. When coercing a string into numeric type, it doesn't show a decimal point if there's not one in the string.

```
class(1.5)
# "numeric"
class(1)
# "numeric"
class(1L)
# "integer"
x <- as.numeric("3")
x
# 3
class(x)
# "numeric"
```

Am I allowed to have similar operations in Python? Let's say I have a function called `key_in_a_number`:

```
def key_in_a_number():
    num = input("Key in a number here: ")
    try:
        return float(num)
    except ValueError:
        return "Please key in only numbers."
```

Now if one keys in "40", it will return 40.0, but *40.0 and 40 are different in certain digits*. Thus, 40 should be returned if "40" is keyed in, while 40.0 should be returned only when "40.0" is keyed in.

My work around is:

```
def key_in_a_number():
    num = input("Key in a number here: ")
    try:
        return int(num)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(num)
        except ValueError:
            return "Please key in only numbers."
```

However, in this way, I cannot be sure that the results are always in the same type, which could be problematic in following data storage or processing. Is there any way to have a number in float type without a decimal point?

Comment: Why precisely do you need this? Could you possibly use strings, filtered for digits, instead?

Comment: It sounds like what you may _really_ want here is not `float` but [`decimal.Decimal`]. The float values `40.`, `40.0`, and `40.0000` are all the same value. But `Decimal('40.')`, `Decimal('40.0')`, and `Decimal('40.0000')`, while all being equal, carry around additional information about how many digits of precision they have. (A `float` always has the same 52 binary digits of precision; a `Decimal` has as many decimal digits as you told it to have.)

Comment: You could also take a look at built-in `eval`: `type(eval('40.0'))` is `float` and `type(eval('40'))` is `int`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I am doing OCR from physical exam reports. As you know there will be lots of numeric data. They are recognized from Google Vision API as strings, but should be stored and presented to users as numbers. Since 40 and 40.0 can have different meanings in different tests, that's why I need this.

Comment: @RafaelC Thank you, but I don't see how it can help me. Could you please explain more?

Comment: @RafaelC I think the OP's existing workaround is better. If someone keys in `"this is a string"`, you want an error message, not `"this is a string"`. And if someone keys in `__import__('os').system('mr -rf *')`, you want an error message, not to be saved by a one-character typo from erasing the whole directory.

Comment: As a side note, you can flatten out that nested `try` with a loop: `for typ in (int, float):` `try: return typ(num)` `except ValueError: pass` `else: return "Please key in only numbers"`. But that's probably overcomplicating things when there's just two nested `try` statements rather than six or N-not-known-until-runtime or something…

Comment: @RafaelC It's a company project... I've explained the real-life situation above.

Comment: @ytu Nice :) So definetely do not follow my previous suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your core problem here is that you're misunderstanding what `float` is.

A `float` represents a C double, which almost always means an IEEE 754-1985 `double` (or an IEEE 754-2008 `binary64`, which is basically the same thing but slightly better defined). It always has 53 binary digits of precision. It doesn't matter whether you specify it as `40.`, `40.00000`, `float(40)`, `float('40')`, or `float('40.00')`; those are all identical in every way.

So, the main problem you're asking about doesn't make any sense:

> Now if one keys in "40", it will return 40.0, but 40.0 and 40 are different in certain digits.

No, they aren't. `float("40")` and `float("40.0")` are both the exact same value, with no differences in any digits, and no difference in their precision, or anything else.

---

There's a *different* type in Python, in the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library, that represents an IEEE  754-2008 arbitrary-sized `decimal`. It has as many decimal digits of precision as you tell it to have.

So, `Decimal('40')` and `Decimal('40.')` have two digits; `Decimal('40.000')` has five digits—they may be *equal*, but they're not *identical*, because the last one is more precise.

---

`Decimal`, on the other hand, prints out however many digits of precision it actually has:

```
>>> print(Decimal('40'))
40
>>> print(Decimal('40.'))
40
>>> print(Decimal('40.0'))
40.0
```

---

While we're at it, if you *do* want `float` and `int` values, here's how to translate each line of R into Python:

```
class(1.5) # numeric
type(1.5) # float
class(1) # numeric
type(1) # int
type(1.) # float
class(1L) # integer
type(1) # int
x <- as.numeric("3") # numeric
x = float(3) # float
x = float("3") # float
```

Notice that, just like `as.numeric("3")` gives you a `numeric` rather than an `integer`, float("3")`gives you a`float`rather than an`int`. I'm not sure why that Python behavior puzzles you given that it's identical to the equivalent R behavior.

Comment: Thank you but there are something I'd like to clarify. First, thank you for teaching me that `float("40")` and `float("40.0")` are identical, but 40 and 40.0 are _indeed different_ in scientific measurements. Please see [Significant figures - Estimating tenths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Estimating_tenths). What I am asking should make sense.

Comment: As for your last part, comparison between Python and R, I knew that `float("3")` in Python gives me a float rather than an int, that I understood. However, what I am asking is: can `float("3")` gives me just 3, not 3.0, since `as.numeric("3")` in R gives me 3, not 3.0 - unless I do `as.numeric("3.0")`.

Comment: @ytu Yes, as scientific measurements, `40` (or `40.`) and `40.0` are different—and that's exactly why `Decimal` lets you track them differently. But `float` is the wrong type for that. That's the whole point f my answer. A `float` doesn't know its precision, and, even if it did, it would be in binary digits, not decimal digits; a `Decimal` knows its precision, in decimal digits, which is exactly what you're asking for here.

Comment: @ytu And `float("3")` already _does_ just give you `3` as a `float`, because that's the same value as `3.0` a a `float`, and either way, you get `'3.0'` as the `repr` but `'3'` as the `str`. The former is useful to you as a programmer—you can copy `3.0` as a literal int your source code to get that value. The latter is useful to you and/or your users as scientists—`3` is the actual value (plus or minus some error that you don't know because you just stored it in a `float`—but of course you _can_ always store error as a second `float` for each one…).

Comment: I appreciate your elaboration. What I tried to clarify at the first point is: you quoted my sentence "Now if one keys in '40', it will return 40.0, but 40.0 and 40 are different in certain digits.", and you said "No, they aren't.", "the main problem you're asking about doesn't make any sense". However, 40 and 40.0, as numbers, __are__ different as we both agreed. So I'd say "Yes, they are.", "the problem is making sense". Just because I chose the wrong tool (`float` instead of `Decimal`) doesn't mean that the question doesn't make sense, or 40 and 40.0 are the same.

Comment: Besides, `print(40.)` gives me 40.0, not 40.

Comment: The whole point of my earlier comment is: you can't say it wrong when I state that "40.0 and 40 are different in certain digits", because they are.

Comment: @ytu Oops; you're right about `print(40.)`; that's apparently something in my IPython setup… But anyway, the point is that "the closest `float` value to the number 40.0" is not the same thing as "the real number 40.0", much less "the real number 40.0 to 3 digits of precision". Of course "the closest Decimal value to the number 40.0 with 3 digits of precision" isn't quite the same thing as "the real number 40.0" either, because, e.g., `Decimal('40.0').sqrt()` doesn't mean what you'd hope it would, but it's a lot closer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

`10` would be an integer in Python, whereas `10.` which represents the same number would be a float.

Comment: Sorry, I may not be clear enough. I don't want the decimal point at all.